# NSURLRequest - encode url for NSURLRequest POST Body (iPhone objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, http

I am sending a post using NSURLRequest.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:someUrlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [parameterString length]];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Within the body of the Request I am encoding the following NVP:

returnURL=http://someSite.com

The post is going through successfully, but I get an error back.
The error states an invalid url.

So, I changed it to:

returnURL=http:%2F%2FsomeSite.com

With the same error.

I have also double checked it with Todd Ditchendorf's HTTP Client, with the same results.

I know I must be encoding this wrong can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks 
Corey

**UPDATE:
Thanks to those who answered.  I missed an ampersand in my NVP values.  So of course, as soon as I fixed it, everything was fine.  What I suspectede, the encoding of a url in the body of the post was incorrect. I am not using the ASIHTTPRequest framework, but it did help me troubleshoot the problem (overkill for what I needed).
**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider using Ben Copsey's [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) framework for generating and sending synchronous and asynchronous HTTTP requests (POST and GET):

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:@"http://someSite.com"] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:@"myValue1" forKey:@"myFormField1"];
[request setPostValue:@"myValue2" forKey:@"myFormField2"];
// etc.
[request start];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error)
  NSString *response = [request responseString];
```

His framework is a huge time-saver.

Comment: ASIHttpRequest is freaking awesome!!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but

```
[parameterString length]
```

is often not be equal to the length of

```
[parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

because UTF8 encodes characters with varying numbers of bytes.