# Upload and download data from server with Cocoa Touch?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection

How can I upload/download data from a server in Cocoa Touch. Here's what I have so far...

```
-(void)uploadSchedule:(id)sender
{
    NSData *content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.dataFilePath];
    NSString *stuff = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:content encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thetis.lunarmania.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[stuff dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"great success!");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // this method is called when the server has determined that it
    // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse

    // it can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
    // redirect, so each time we reset the data.
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere

    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // append the new data to the receivedData
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere

    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    [receivedData release];

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // do something with the data
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
    [cat setImage:image];
    [image release];

    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSURLCredential *newCredential;
        newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"ican@moeyo.org"
                                                 password:@"icanican"
                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
               forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        // inform the user that the user name and password
        // in the preferences are incorrect
        //[self showPreferencesCredentialsAreIncorrectPanel:self];
    }
}
```

I'm so lost...

Answer (score 1):

The code crashes because you over-release `connection`. Review the [Cocoa memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).

Aside from that, you'll have to be more specific about what problem you're having with it.

BTW, the term is “instance variable”, not “method instance”. An instance variable is a variable inside of an instance, and has nothing to do with methods.

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered here:

[NSURLRequest - encode url for NSURLRequest POST Body (iPhone objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787582/nsrequest-encode-url-for-nsrequest-post-body-iphone-objective-c)

The accepted answer uses [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) which is similar to one I've used, and makes it really easy to post/get from an HTML form. Here's an example (from past stackoverflow)

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:@"http://someSite.com"] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:@"myValue1" forKey:@"myFormField1"];
[request setPostValue:@"myValue2" forKey:@"myFormField2"];
// etc.
[request start];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error)
  NSString *response = [request responseString];
```

Answer (score 0):

And if your file is big, you should better use `NSFilehandle`, to write data inside `didReceiveData`, instead of appending.