# iPhone > Submitting a web form, handle cookies

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, post, webforms, curl

I'm not at all sure where to get started with the following. Bascially the scenario Is, from my iPhone app I want to be able to login to a web form (via username/password combo) and perform another action. I want the process to be able to handle session persistence via cookies.

My first thoughts were to look at going down the cURL route as I have done similiar with Python/PHP. So basically is there a viable alternative in the Foundation Framework or is my best choice to look at compiling my own cURL framework?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Start here: [Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Some related answers that might be helpful:

- [Upload and download data from server with Cocoa Touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204224/upload-and-download-data-from-server-with-cocoa-touch)
- [HttpBasicAuthentication in IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761445/httpbasicauthentication-in-iphone)
- [NSURLRequest - encode url for NSURLRequest POST Body (iPhone objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787582/nsrequest-encode-url-for-nsrequest-post-body-iphone-objective-c)
- [Google App Engine with ClientLogin Interface for Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471898/google-app-engine-with-clientlogin-interface-for-objective-c)