# NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPBody doesn't work

Tags: cocoa, nsurlrequest

I want to make an HTTP request to a server and get some data.
Here is my code:

```
NSString *post = @"mode=1";  
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];  
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://example.com" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
//if i will give the url http://example.com?mode=1 it works  
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];  
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
[theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];`
```

if the server will take the mode=1 parameter it will make an sql query and return some data.
this way it doesn't work and i think it's something about the `setHTTPBody`.
if i will put the parameter `mode=1` straight to the url it will work.
Can you tell me where i am wrong? Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Does the server support `POST` requests?

Comment: ye i think it is. it is a xampp installation(apache+php)

Comment: Test it using another method.

Comment: what do you mean? btw this is the server: http://ozmax.dyndns.org/dataManager  
it returns data with the url parameter mode=1

Comment: What I mean is find some other method to ensure that `POST` requests are accepted by the web server.

Comment: i made an html form and used action="post". it worked fine( i printed the $_POST).

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLRequest - encode url for NSURLRequest POST Body (iPhone objective-C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787582/nsurlrequest-encode-url-for-nsurlrequest-post-body-iphone-objective-c)

Comment: It sounds like you want to encode mode=1 as form data.

Answer (score 0):

> if i will give the url http://example.com?mode=1 it works

Then that's a GET, not a POST request. So use GET or let your server handle POST.

Comment: if i will use  
    `[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];`  
i get this error::
Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" UserInfo=0x7174e90 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://ozmax.dyndns.org/dataManager, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://ozmax.dyndns.org/dataManager}